# Rails Dropdown menu not working / hash link not working? Maybe turbolink error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a dropdown menu called information that works on the first click load... But then when I switch to another page and try to make the dropdown load it doesn't. Any ideas?

http://www.sonomaproud.com/

**The "Information page" has the dropdown.**

Here is my html:

```
<div class="ma-subnav__item" data-turbolinks="false">
            <div class="content" data-turbolinks="false">                                        
                <ul class="normal-ul" data-turbolinks="false">
<li class="dropdown" data-turbolinks="false">
  <a href="#" data-turbolinks="false" class="link-reset" data-toggle="dropdown">Information <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-turbolinks="false">
    <li><%= link_to "Why", welcome_why_path, class: "link-reset" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "How", welcome_how_path, class: "link-reset" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Resources", welcome_resources_path, class: "link-reset" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", welcome_feedback_path, class: "link-reset" %></li>
  </ul>
</li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My css is fine:

It loads just not when you switch between pages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are only applying the dropdown behaviour on the first page load. You will need to apply the behaviour on `turbolinks:load`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
  // … the rest
})
```

You do not need the `data-turbolinks` attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! My town in sonoma just got hit with a major fire, so I built this site to help out! This fix was just what I was looking for.